# Blazor WASM - NavLink with dynamic href value

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a Blazor WASM application, I have a data entry page, and when the logged-in user tries to leave the page, I check to see if the model has any pending changes so I can ask the user for confirmation.
I made this with the NavigationLock component and the OnInternalNavigation method.
In the OnInternalNavigation method I use a variable to store the target location (could be / or something else) to set the NavLink href, so that when the user confirms to leave the page he can go to the new route.
This works fine, but when I click the confirm button to leave the page, nothing happens.

Is it possible to set a NavLink href based on the value of a variable in the @code section?

**The .razor page with NavigationLock and confirm modal**

```html
<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnInternalNavigation">
</NavigationLock>

<TelerikWindow Width="320px" Height="fit-content" Modal="true" Centered="true" @bind-Visible="@HasPendingChanges">
    <WindowTitle>Pending changes</WindowTitle>
    <WindowContent>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column space-y-8 px-2 py-4">
            <div>
                <span>Pending changes detected</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end space-x-4">
                <TelerikButton ThemeColor="@ThemeConstants.Button.ThemeColor.Base"
                               Size="@ThemeConstants.Button.Size.Small"
                               OnClick="@(() => HasPendingChanges = false)">
                    <span>Undo</span>
                </TelerikButton>
                <NavLink href="@TargetLocation">
                    <TelerikButton ThemeColor="@ThemeConstants.Button.ThemeColor.Primary"
                                   Size="@ThemeConstants.Button.Size.Small">
                        <span>Leave</span>
                    </TelerikButton>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    </WindowContent>
</TelerikWindow>
```

**The code behind**

```cs
public bool HasPendingChanges { get; set; }
public string TargetLocation { get; set; }

public void OnInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext locationContext) {
   if (ModelContext.IsModified()) {
      locationContext.PreventNavigation();
      HasPendingChanges = true;
      TargetLocation = locationContext.TargetLocation;
   }
}
```

I tried to use a NavLink component with href binded with the value of a string variable, set on the code behind when the OnInternalNavigation method fires.
I also tried to remove the NavLink component and use just a button where the OnClick method changes the location with the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(location)`.

Both implementations dont't work because the link doesn't change, as if no method is called when I click the confirm button.

Comment: Is there any code that make `ModelContext.IsModified()` become `false` so you don't lock user in that URL before or when they click Leave?

Comment: I already checked, `IsModified()` always returns true. In fact, in the chrome dev console I see the new path in the href, but when I click it, nothing happens.

Comment: That's the issue. In your `OnInternalNavigation`, if `IsModified` is `true`, you prevent user from navigating.

Comment: Ok, and this is what I want because I have to ask the user for a confirmation to leave the page. And when he confirms, I change the route by `NavigationManager`. What's wrong? 
The `locationContext.PreventNavigation();` blocks all routes changes? 

The flow I would like to implement is as follows: 
- the user changes the data in the data entry page; 
- when he tries to leave the page without saving the data, I show a popup for confirmation; 
- f the user confirms then he leaves the page losing all the data he entered, alternatively he remains on the data entry page.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Right now your code doesn't reflect that. Whenever user click a link with `ModelContext.IsModified()`, you always call `PreventNavigation`. You need to have a variable or something to know if the user deliberately ignores changes and just wants to leave.

Comment: I think something is not clear, maybe I could explain better. 
I have a page with a form based on the model and if I change at least one property I don't have to leave the page without a confirmation because I might lose data. If I confirm, I lost my data, otherwise I can continue the data entry. 
So, IMO the flow is concretely correct because the `PreventNavigation` only fires if the `ModelContext` has pending changes. The variable I use to know if the user ignores the changes in the onClick event on the `NavLink` with the new route.

Comment: Sorry @LukeVo, I realized what you wrote. Since the `OnInternalNavigation` method fires both when I change route and when I confirm to leave the page, I need to store this confirmation. In this way, I can change the route when the user confirms (and the `IgnoreChanges` variable is true). 

 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `OnInternalNavigation` is called also when the user tries to leave and `ModelContext.IsModified()` is still `true`, your `PreventNavigation()` is called all the time.

You need to add something else to check if the user has confirmed to just want to leave or not:

```cs
public void OnInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext locationContext) {
   if (ModelContext.IsModified()) {
      if (userClickedConfirm) // Something like this
      {
         // Ignore, just let them navigate
      }
      else
      {
         locationContext.PreventNavigation();
         HasPendingChanges = true;
         TargetLocation = locationContext.TargetLocation;
      }
   }
}
```